# Getting Excel Macro to Loop Task, Slightly Different Each Time

Tags: excel, vba

I hope someone can help me, as I know that the macro I am trying to create would save about 30 minutes' work if it comes off.

Once a month I download a financial transactions report; the search variables I need to use are in column C. The number of rows for each search variable changes from month to month. I need to search for all rows containing a given variable (e.g. VDEN, VDEM VDEF; these are exact search terms), copy all rows containing the variable and paste them into a one of five workbooks, each with several worksheets in it.

I have some code to do this with one term and one worksheet location, but I don't know how to loop it so that it goes back for a new variable and starts the whole process all over again.

This is what I have already:

```
Sub Macro2()

Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\jo\Desktop\Month End.xlsx"
Columns("A:L").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Cells.Find("Total:").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet.Range("a1:l" & lastrow)
.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="VDEN"
.Offset(1, 0).Copy

 End With

Workbooks.Open Filename:="X:\admin\Finance\2016-17\Transaction Lists\Sample Transactions 2016-17.xlsx"

Windows("Month End.xlsx").Activate
Windows("Sample Transactions 2016-17.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Pre-Sessional").Select
Columns("A:L").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

Windows("Sample Transactions 2016-17.xlsx").Activate
Worksheets("Pre-Sessional").Activate
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D:D,F:F,G:G,H:H,K:K").Select

Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

Windows("Month End.xlsx").Activate
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData


 End Sub
```

Can anybody help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the OR clause in your filter.  I'd suggest recording doing a multiple selection filter, like this [And Or Criteria](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm)  about 2/3 down.   Or use a for next loop on an array.  Like so [Looping Array](http://www.homeandlearn.org/arrays_and_loops.html)

Comment: I don't know if the OR would work as each variable is specific to one single paste location. I'm not searching for more than one variable at a time.

Comment: Use the array option then, enclose your code in one of the methods shown in the link